# Postgresql: Execute query write results to csv file - datatype money gets broken into two columns because of comma

Tags: postgresql

After running Execute query write results to file - the columns in my output file for datatype money get broken into two columns. e.g if my revenue is $500 it is displayed correctly. But, if my revenue is $1,500.00 - there is an issue. It gets broken into two columns $1 and $500.00

Can you please help me getting my results in a csv file in a single column for datatype money?

Answer (score 1):

What is this command "execute query write results to file"? Do you mean `COPY`? If so, have a look at the `FORCE QUOTE` option http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Eg.

`COPY yourtable to '/some/path/and/file.csv' CSV HEADER FORCE QUOTE *;`

Note: if the application that is consuming the csv files still fails because of the comma, you can change the delimiter from "," to whatever works for you (eg. "|").

Additionally, if you do not want CSV, but you do want TSV, you can omit the `CSV HEADER` keywords and the results will output in tab-separated format.

Answer (score 0):

Comma is the list separator of our computer for some regions, some region semicolon is the list separator. so I think you need to replace the comma when you write it to csv.

Comment: Using `FORCE QUOTE` with the `COPY` command double-quotes the specified columns, and most applications that ingest CSV files should handle embedded commas properly.